# Opposite numbers order - Android - Hebrew/Arab

Tags: android, numbers, hebrew

Whenever & Wherever I write numbers on Hebrew/Arab Languages - The Apear the opposite.
Example: When I write 10, it will appear as 01.
Or When I write 3.14 it will appear as 41.3.

How can I fix this?

Comment: convert the number to string and then string to back to integer

Comment: Did you set the EditView inputType to number?

Comment: What is EditView?!